# Get Sum of Javascript Date function

Tags: javascript, html

I have code for get time difference form two time

```
        var starthours = document.getElementById("time3").value;
        var endhours = document.getElementById("time4").value;
        start = starthours.split(".");
        end = endhours.split(".");
        var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
        var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);
        var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
        var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
        diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
    document.getElementById("hourdiff").value = (hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours + "." + (minutes < 9 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
```

But now I have to add another time field for this results, I get that value using this code

```
var timetv = document.getElementById("timetv").value;

And I want to add this to above time difference how to do that, Please help me.. 

Start time = 10.30
End time = 12.30
Time TV = 01.15

Resualt = (End Time - Start time) + Time TV
```

And answer should be = 3.15

Comment: give some context please. Is your input value (all 3) plain time values or do they have date? Judging by your use of split, they should be just time and in `hh.mm` format. If this is the case why should they be converted to date format and then use `getTime`? can't we simply do (hours*60)+minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
var starthours = document.getElementById("time3").value;
var endhours = document.getElementById("time4").value;
var timetv = document.getElementById("timetv").value;

start = starthours.split(".");
end = endhours.split(".");
tvtime = timetv.split(".");

var startDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, start[0], start[1], 0);
var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, end[0], end[1], 0);

var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);    

hours = hours + parseInt(tvtime[0]);
minutes = minutes + parseInt(tvtime[1]);
```

Comment: @JoelCampbell : actully we have already hours and minutes so we don't need to convert it into time like this var tvtimedate = new Date(0, 0, 0, tvtime[0], tvtime[1], 0).

Answer (score 0):

this one is for getting the value when you already have the dates parsed into Date object from your form.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLReS/

```
var time1 = new Date('2013/08/12 10:30');
var time2 = new Date('2013/08/12 12:30');
var time3 = new Date('2013/08/12 1:15');

var result = (time2.getTime() - time1.getTime()) + time3.getTime();
var resultTime = new Date(result);
alert(resultTime);
```

The other thing is however getting these objects, and this one depends on your date format.

Comment: that's because IE does not support "2013-08-12 10:30" format - try it now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, what is your problem.

```
var d = new Date(
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 12, 30) -
    new Date(0, 0, 0, 10, 30) +
    (+new Date(0, 0, 0, 1, 15)) // transform Date into timestamp
);
[d.getHours(), d.getMinutes()]; // [3, 15]
```

Also, I usually replace

```
(hours < 9 ? "0" : "") + hours
```

with

```
("0" + hours).slice(-2)
```